# Git push django project error - No such file or directory

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I typed `git push heroku master` in the command (Terminal)
then this error occurs

> remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ktietz/src/ci/alabaster_1611921544520/work'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Running `git push` does not try to install any packages. Where exactly do you run this command and where does the error occur?

Comment: @mkrieger1, here is the link to the image https://drive.google.com/file/d/11t5jIKcUrlpG_JBmmebdGQkeFVZ9yacX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello @Winston check your ***requirements.txt*** file I think you've put some path inside it so remove it ***requirements.txt*** file should contain packages not path

Comment: Git has nothing to do with this error: it's a Heroku issue. Git is merely a transport, shuffling commits from you to Heroku, and taking the error messages from Heroku back to you.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Thanks For Help, here is the link to my requirement.txt file: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jlqPFgzR1gOa5F6PXIc8uHcAWxa0Ykp-nH7FWgTwBuk/edit, after I delete the path of the module in the file. I had type 'git init' > 'git add .' > 'git commit -m "Initial Project"' > 'git push heroku master'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with your requirements.txt file which contains all of your needed libraries and packages to be installed on remote.

Do You have your requirement.txt file in your project root folder(where manage.py file resides)  ???

if not then you need to first activate your virtual environment and then create requirement.txt file by:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

you can see details on how to create and activate virtual environment here: official documentation    https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

after you have your requirements.txt file ready then run the same git command

```
git push heroku master
```

if already have requirements.txt file in your project root folder then there is an isssue in your requirements.txt file which contains dependencies that might be incompatible.

Comment: thanks for your help, I had do what you tell me before, however it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**First :**  check your **requirements.txt** file it should contain only `package_name==<version>` not path.

---

**Second :** your file name should be **requirements.txt** not **requirement.txt** because heroku idenifies python app by **requirements.txt** file name.

---

**Third :** check that your **requirements.txt** file is in root
directory *`(where manage.py exists)`*

Comment: I can ensure that I already did what you told me to do, and not only once, but the command line keeps telling me that there is no such file and directory. However, I did upload the initial and cleaned the git.

Comment: Hello @Winston did you followed any tutorials?

Comment: Yes, I did followed the tutorial video

Comment: Hello @Winston by looking at your question It's hard to figure out what's the problem if you provide some detail like which tutorial you followed or providing full error etc. it will be easy for us to help you out.

Comment: this is the tutorial video I watched. https://shrtm.nu/LYpg

Comment: Your method is correct, the reason of mine couldn't work is there are too many unnecessary package in the requirement.txt, which the Heroku can not maintain it.