# Unable to push on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

```
Processing /D:/bld/astroid_1640971040574/work
remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/D:/bld/astroid_1640971040574/work'
```

I am having above error while trying to upload to heroku using `git push heroku main`.
How can I push the changes?

Comment: This is not a Git issue. Note that it appears that your Heroku instance is using Linux and you are attempting to get it to use Windows path names. This would be your mistake: you'll need to use Linux names on Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Either what you are specifying includes a PATH (a local path which is only valid on your workstation, you local development environment).
Or what you are executing includes a path.

- On the specification side, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70652446/6309), check your `requirements.txt` file content (no path should be there)
- On the execution side, [make sure your `server.js` is not using `PWD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39535945/6309).

Answer (score 0):

might be your project is in master branch of github.But you are trying to push main branch in heroku. Please check the branch in github where you uploaded the project carefully then push accordingly. Please upload with the screanshot of all command you given there.